# Matching between two sequences of characters

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to match all lines under Targets: and up to Build Configurations. So in this situation I would like to match `OglGlm` and `OglGlmTest`, and any others that may appear under Targets:

The following captures `OglGlm`:

```
Targets:\s([^=\t\n]*)
```

but I don't want to keep adding `\s([^=\t\n]*)`.

Input data:

```
Information about project "OglGlm":

    Targets:
        OglGlm
        OglGlmTests

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

    Schemes:
        OglGlm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below grep command would print all the lines which are present in-between the line which has `Targets:` and `Build Configurations:` .

```
$ grep -oPz '^\s*Targets:[^\n]*\n\K[\s\S]*?(?=\n[ \t]*Build Configurations:)' file
        OglGlm
        OglGlmTests
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final and `[\s\S]*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters.`(?=..)` called positive lookahead assertion which asserts whether a match is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `awk`

```
awk '!NF {f=0} f; /Targets:/ {f=1}' file
        OglGlm
        OglGlmTests
```

It prints all line after `Targets` is found, until first empty line.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks for the alternative.

Comment: @DarthVadar123451 You are welcome.  If you like it, you can give it +1 :)